# How ro reuse .xed file recorded by kinect studio in another application

Tags: kinect, kinect-sdk, kinect.toolbox

I have several .xed files recorded by Kinect Studio. I have to use them to test my application. Do you have any idea how to do that?

I didn't recorded these files using my application, but I need to check gestures used in them with my own gesture recognizer app.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I suggest :

- Run your app
- Start Kinect Studio and connect your app to it
- Open your xed file
- Hit play

Your app should act as if the movie is a live kinect stream.

Note that **you must have a Kinect plugged in your computer to be able to use .xed files to send recorded data to any other Kinect app**.
Without a physical Kinect plugged in, you can only use .xed files to view recordings stored in them.