# programming on kinect without kinect sensor

Tags: opencv, kinect, sensors, kinect-sdk

I recorded some motions as .xed file by Kinect Studio 1.8 and sensor Kinect for Windows at my University. And now I want to use this .xed file instead of kinect sensor, because at home I don't have it and I want to improve my app.

When I did points from [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21342694/how-ro-reuse-xed-file-recorded-by-kinect-studio-in-another-application/36936573#36936573) it is not working, there is a message box that I need connect kinect sensor.

How I can open my app without kinect sensor and test it with this .xed file? I read about Fakenect but I can't find any documentation how to use it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How ro reuse .xed file recorded by kinect studio in another application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21342694/how-ro-reuse-xed-file-recorded-by-kinect-studio-in-another-application)

Comment: I tag it as "similar problem". It is not working for me.

Comment: In that question there is an answer which explains that it is not possible to use .xed files for emulating a fake kinect with Kinect Studio without having an actual Kinect plugged in. This has been fixed in MS Kinect SDK 2 and Kinect Studio 2, where you can use files recorded with Kinect Studio with no need of any actual device connected